# Alexa Invocation name with Intent not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm developing a skill where I want users to be able to fire up the skill by providing a slot value at invocation by telling

`Alexa start [skill name] for the [slot value]`

In the Alexa simulator, when I enter this as a text I only get `<audio response only>` from the simulator.

When I do it in two steps it does work:

Me: `Alexa start [skill name]`

Alexa: `For which election?`

Me: `For the [slot value]`

Alexa: `Okay here we go...`

Is there something I've missed to setup for it to work?

This is the code:

```
var newSessionHandlers = {
  NewSession: function() {
    this.emit(
      ':ask',
      'For which election?',
    );
  },
  ChooseElection: function() {
    this.emit(':tell', 'Here we go');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are set of supported phrases for invoking your skill with an intent. Most of them has `<connecting words>` that has to be included while invoking a skill with a specific request.

In your case **start** has to be followed by an **and** followed by utterence.

ie,

```
Start <invocation name> and <some action>
```

Please refer this [page](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/understanding-how-users-invoke-custom-skills.html#cert-invoke-specific-request) for the supported phrases for invoking your skill with an intent.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. That did make me understand it better but I couldn't get it to work yet. My skill will be in german - do you know if the same rules apply for german, as there's not tab for german in the documentation?

Comment: There is note in docs regarding invocation name in German. "German skills only: The invocation name is a compound of two or more words. In this case, the word must form an actual word in the skill's language to ensure that Alexa can recognize it"

Comment: I have the same problem as OP; your answer says that it has to be called different from the user, but it doesn't work no matter how i put it.